# cannot remove items in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

The function of the program is to remove duplicates from an `Arraylist<Character>`. In the static method `removeDuplicate()`, I first assign the position of duplicates into a `LinkedList`, then remove the duplicates in the `ArrayList` by getting their positions in the `LinkedList`. If you enter input as a, a, a, a, you would see that the duplicate is not removed. Can anyone help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Duplicate2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList <Character> list = new ArrayList<> (2);
        Character y = 'A';
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 4 characters");
        for(int n = 0; n <4; n++)
        {
            y = kb.next().charAt(0); // no matter how many character in a line, only the first is kept.
            list.add(y);
        }
        System.out.println("Stop entering input.");
        Duplicate2.removeDuplicate(list);
        for (int n = 0; n < list.size(); n++)
            System.out.println(list.get(n));
    }

    public static void removeDuplicate (ArrayList <Character> data)
    {
        int k = data.size ();
        int t = 0;
        LinkedList <Integer> duplicatePosition = new LinkedList<>();
        ArrayList <Character> copyList = new ArrayList <> (2);
        for (int n = 0; n < data.size(); n ++)
        {
            Character x = data.get(n);
            if (copyList.isEmpty())
                copyList.add(x);
            else
            {
                for (int m = 0; m <copyList.size(); m++)
                {
                    if (x.equals(copyList.get(m)))
                    {
                        duplicatePosition.add(n);
                        t++;
                        break;
                        //data.remove(n);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        copyList.add(x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Position of duplicate:");
        for (int n = 0; n < duplicatePosition.size(); n++)
            System.out.println(duplicatePosition.get(n));
        System.out.println("Start to remove duplicates");
        for (int n = 0; n< duplicatePosition.size(); n++)
        {
            System.out.println("Position " + duplicatePosition.get(n) + " would be removed.");
            data.remove(duplicatePosition.get(n));
            for (int m = 0; m < data.size(); m ++)
                System.out.println(data.get(m));
            if ((n+1)<duplicatePosition.size())
                duplicatePosition.set(n+1, duplicatePosition.get(n+1) -1);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the loop in which you attempt to remove elements :

```
    for (int n = 0; n< duplicatePosition.size(); n++)
    {
        System.out.println("Position " + duplicatePosition.get(n) + " would be removed.");
        data.remove(duplicatePosition.get(n));
        ...
    }
```

The problem with that is that each time you remove the `duplicatePosition.get(n)`'th element from `data`, all the following elements are moved (i.e. the original `(duplicatePosition.get(n)+1)`'th element becomes the new `duplicatePosition.get(n)`'th element).

So if, for example, duplicatePosition contains 1,2,3 and you call data.remove(duplicatePosition.get(0)), you remove the element with index 1 from data and the index of the element with index 2 in data would change to 1. Therefore data.remove(duplicatePosition.get(1)) won't remove it.

To account for that, you must count the elements you already removed, and subtract the count from the index to be removed :

```
    int removed = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n< duplicatePosition.size(); n++)
    {
        System.out.println("Position " + (duplicatePosition.get(n)-removed) + " would be removed.");
        data.remove(duplicatePosition.get(n)-removed);
        removed++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach:

```
    // your original list is declared as 
    // List<Character> lst = ...
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(lst);
    lst = new ArrayList<Character>();
    lst.addAll(set);
    // now lst doesn't contain duplicates
```